# Unable to create an IAM role in AWS China Ningxia region

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to use terraform to create an IAM role in AWS China Ningxia region.

Here's my folder structure

```
.
├── main.tf
└── variables.tf
```

Here's the content of `main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
  region  = var.region
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name               = "TestRole"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy_doc.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "access_key" {}
variable "secret_key" {}
variable "region" {}
```

After running the following command

```
terraform apply \
  -var 'access_key=<my_access_key>' \
  -var 'secret_key=<my_secret_key>' \
  -var 'region=cn-northwest-1'
```

I got an error saying `Error: Error creating IAM Role TestRole: MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"ec2.amazonaws.com"`.

This terraform script works correctly in other regions of AWS (Tokyo, Singapore, ...). It seems like that AWS China is a little bit different from other regions.

Here's the message before I type `yes` to terraform:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_iam_role.role will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
      + arn                   = (known after apply)
      + assume_role_policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action    = "sts:AssumeRole"
                      + Effect    = "Allow"
                      + Principal = {
                          + Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                        }
                      + Sid       = ""
                    },
                ]
              + Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
      + create_date           = (known after apply)
      + force_detach_policies = false
      + id                    = (known after apply)
      + max_session_duration  = 3600
      + name                  = "TestRole"
      + path                  = "/"
      + unique_id             = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.
```

Does anyone know how to create an IAM role like mine with terraform in AWS China?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `aws iam get-account-authorization-details` to view the current IAM roles in my AWS China accounts, which are created using AWS console.

Then I found lines containing `"Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com.cn"`.

So using `ec2.amazonaws.com.cn` to replace `ec2.amazonaws.com` works without any problem.

I mean the content of `main.tf` should be

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.access_key
  secret_key = var.secret_key
  region  = var.region
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name               = "TestRole"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy_doc.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_doc" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com.cn"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

China is different as you said.

`ec2.amazonaws.com` will not work in China, instead you have to use something along the lines of `ec2.cn-northwest-1.amazonaws.com.cn`

Here you have the list of all endpoints https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/aws/latest/userguide/endpoints-Ningxia.html

Also a recommended read about IAM in China: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/aws/latest/userguide/iam.html#general-info

Comment: Using `ec2.cn-northwest-1.amazonaws.com.cn` instead of `ec2.amazonaws.com` doesn't work, either. The error message is `Invalid principal in policy: "SERVICE":"ec2.cn-northwest-1.amazonaws.com.cn"`.

Comment: @Brian can you check whether you can create this policy directly using the AWS Console? (I don't have AWS China accounts..). If you can create it, we can narrow this down to something in Terraform, because according to the doc, `ec2.cn-northwest-1.amazonaws.com.cn` is a valid and the correct principal for that action.

Comment: I can create an IAM role with that inline policy through AWS console in AWS China.

Answer (score 0):

Like so much in AWS, it is all fully documented... but the real challenge is in finding [the documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/aws/latest/userguide/endpoints-Ningxia.html).

As you wrote, Brian, the answer is to use `ec2.amazonaws.com.cn` instead of `ec2.amazonaws.com` when working in China.  But I thought the documentation above might be helpful since it includes all mappings.

---

Also, highly related:

If you use Terraform and you need to manage resources both in China and outside, you can use the data source `aws_partition` to help you generalize across China and non-China:

```
data "aws_partition" "current" {
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {
}
```

Then later if you have something like:

```
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:${data.aws_partition.current.partition}:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/my_cool_role"]
    }
```

Then it will evaluate the ARN as follows:

- China: `arn:aws-cn:iam::<my China account number>:role/my_cool_role`
- Anywhere else: `arn:aws:iam::<my other account number>:role/my_cool_role`

Note that in China it's `aws-cn` whereas it is `aws` otherwise.

This does assume that you have properly set up the two regions, so that "current" reflects back to the Chinese and non-Chinese accounts.